# Why does local variable inside foreach loop conflict with variable declared outside the loop?

Tags: c#

Given this code:

```
List<string> things = new List<string>();

foreach (string thing in things)
{
    string foo = thing.ToUpper();
}

string foo = String.Empty;
```

Why does the compiler complain that foo is declared twice? Surely the instance declared in the foreach loop is only valid within the scope of the loop?

Comment: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ericlippert/archive/tags/declaration+spaces/

Comment: I think your argument breaks down when you consider variable capture

Comment: There are at least half a dozen duplicates of this question. One example: [How does .NET handle variables inside scope](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9705115/how-does-net-handle-variables-inside-scope)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

While you can only refer to the outer `foo` after you declared it, locals are allocated at the beginning of a function which means the inner `foo` will overshadow the outer one, even if it hasn't been declared yet.